# css - display a flat button in jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to have a flat style button in jqm. what I tried is below but still get a tiny line in bottom of it.

```css
.flat-btn,.flat-btn > .ui-btn-inner {
  border-top:0 !important;
  border-bottom:0 !important;
  border:0 !important;
  background:transparent !important;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
  border-radius:0 !important;
  text-shadow:0 !important
}
```

```html
<a data-role="button" href="" class="flat-btn">text</a>
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle, it will help you get your question answered sooner!

Comment: this is a shadow, add `data-shadow="false"` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kyV4M/

Comment: you are correct @Omar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `data-shadow="false"` attribute to the button to remove shadows.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kyV4M/)**

```
<a data-role="button" href="#" class="flat-btn" data-shadow="false">text</a>
```